# Rss feed reader for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

I'm looking to create a cron job that will collect data from multiple rss feeds and store the info in a database table.

Two example's of feeds I'll be parsing:
http://news.google.com/news?ned=ie&topic=n&output=rss
http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/asia

I was wondering if people have suggestions for the best rails gem to use to do this?
(Don't want to start with one to find out half way through that there are limitations/bugs.)

Thanks

Comment: I have used [feedzira](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra) its really cool

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out [Feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra), an excellent feed reader for Rails.

Comment: Took a look there and seems quite good. Just one question, will it decode html entities? For example, if you look at the yahoo and google feeds I mentioned you will see that the 'description' node contains html tags. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it will. Also has a "sanitize" function to strip nodes of harmful tags.

Comment: Is there a gem for Feedzirra?